# How did the Silurians lose their third eye?

Tags: doctor-who, evolution

In the original series of Doctor Who the Doctor [meets the Silurians](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_Who_and_the_Silurians) (Eocenes, Homo Reptilia, Earth Reptile or Indigenous Terrans) which have three eyes, and look like so:

[image: old three eyed silurians]

On of their most striking features is their third eye, which is missing from their appearance in the new series of doctor who.

[image: New silurians without a third Eye]

How did they lose that feature? Is it anything to do with the *Sea Devils* (which from what I've briefly seen did no have a third eye?)

Comment: Different subspecies, I believe it was.

Comment: @MrLister Is that ever mentioned in canon?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Silurians have appeared twice in television stories, in 1970's DW: Doctor Who and the Silurians and then alongside the closely-related race Sea Devils in 1984's DW: Warriors of the Deep. The Sea Devils also appeared in 1972's DW: The Sea Devils.

> The Doctor tells the Silurians that he has met another tribe of homo reptilia, but when they ask him where they are, he replies, "The humans killed them". (DW: Doctor Who and the Silurians)

From that quotation, it is safe to assume there were more than one type of Silurians in the same way there were more than one type of hominid (Homo Sapiens Sapiens, Homo Sapiens Neanderthalis, Homo Sapiens Cro Magnon) on Earth simultaneously (albeit over very wide time spans).